# Git merge without deleting files in current branch

Tags: git, merge

I'm new to git and learning how to use it to integrate it in my workflow.
Currently, here is my branching model ( based on this site ): https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Two permanent branches :
A master branch that represents the current production branch.
A dev branch, well I think its name speak well :-)

I use hotfix branche to solve issues, hotfix is created from master. So : I want to fix the bug on the hotfix branch, and merge it into master and into dev to have my permanent branches (Master and Dev) updated with the fix.

Problem is : on Dev branch, I create new files that are only on this branch (and not yet on master). These files are tracked because commits are made on this branch to include these new files.
When I merge Hotfix into dev, the merge delete the new files on Dev that weren't on Hotfix...

So my question : Is there a way to merge without deleting files in Dev that are not yet on Hotfix ?

```
git status
On branch hotfix
nothing to commit, working tree clean



git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)


git merge hotfix
Updating b34835d..458a2cf
Fast-forward
  98 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 47534 deletions(-)


delete mode 100644 TG_anc/.htaccess
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Controleur.php
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Controleur/Controleur_Ajax.php
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Controleur/Controleur_Avertissements.php
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Controleur/Controleur_Commande.php
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Controleur/Controleur_Intervenants.php
 delete mode 100644 TG_anc/Model/Model.php
```

..etc, all my files that are not on hotfix are deleted.
It's the same if I make a no fast forward merge...
Maybe I am doing something wrong ?

I have tried to put the files in the .gitignore, ti does nothing for this case.

Thank in advance !

Comment: Unless you actively delete files on the hotfix branch (using `git rm` _after_ creating the branch), merging the branch will not delete any files.

Comment: Hotfix was created from master, in wich indeed I had deleted files that were not cecessary.So it could be the source of my problem i guess.

Comment: If you look closely at your output, it says "Fast-forward" when merging hotfix, which means that there are no changes in your `dev` branch which are not in `hotfix`. Depending on how `master` and `dev` relate, if the files were deleted on `master` (but are still present in `dev`) and `hotfix` was created from `master`, then merging `hotfix` will also bring in changes from `master` not yet in dev.

Comment: It's difficult to say how your branches relate to each other. It could help to post the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` to show, which commits are in which branch.

Comment: Knittl : the graph is a big mess, beacause I am learning to use git and made a lot of tests...
But I indeed made what you describe. 
What would have been the good way to make it ? Something with untracking files on dev first ?

Comment: Good way to make what? To me, it looks like Git is behaving like it should. You deleted files on a branch (master) and merge that branch into another branch (dev). The files will now be deleted (because you told Git to delete them)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. Files introduced in one branch will not be deleted when merging another branch that does not have knowledge of the files. Merging *merges* changes, and is **not** overwriting them.

```
git checkout master
git branch hotfix
>file_only_on_master echo jska13
git add file_only_on_master
git commit -m 'adding file to master'
git checkout hotfix
>fix echo 'fix me'
git add fix
git commit -m 'applied very import hotfix'
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
```

In the end, your master branch will contain both files `file_only_on_master` and `fix` (and possibly others which have existed before).

Comment: He is not assuming both files won't exist, he is stating they do not both exist on Dev branch after merging hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your merge commit wasn't created because it is fast-forwarded.

```
A -- B -- C
```

Let's say your master was at A and your hotfix was at C. if you `git merge hotfix` on master branch, it would choose to fast-forward master to C instead of creating a new commit.

2. So you need to force git to create merge commit first.

   You can add `--no-ff` parameter when merging hotfix to force merge commit creation. After that, the branch would look like this:

```
  /-- -- -- M  <-master
 /         /
A -- B -- C    <-hotfix
```

... but the files would be still deleted.

3. You can modify merge commit by force-quitting editor.

   So you want to modify your merge commit M, instead of accepting git's selection. To achieve this, you can crash-exit your merge editor - in case of vim, it's `:cq`.

   If you quit the editor abnormally, the HEAD would be at A but the changes from B, C are applied&staged.

   So you can `git reset` and then `git checkout` them, for example in your case `git reset TG_anc/ && git checkout TG_anc/`.

   After that you can `git merge --continue` to indicate git that you are done with modification willing to continue merge process.

Example:

```sh
SHELL$ git init

SHELL$ touch ./a

SHELL$ git add ./a

SHELL$ git commit -m "A"
[master (root-commit) 63dd4c0] A
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a

SHELL$ git checkout -b hotfix
Switched to a new branch 'hotfix'

SHELL$ git rm a
rm 'a'

SHELL$ git commit -m "B"
[hotfix 105e68f] B
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 a

SHELL$ git checkout master  
Switched to branch 'master'

# Vim editor will show up after this, crash-exit by esc - :cq .
SHELL$ git merge hotfix  --no-ff
Removing a
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

SHELL$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:
    deleted:    a

SHELL$ git reset -- a && git checkout -- a
Unstaged changes after reset:
D   a

SHELL$ git merge --continue
[master b769fdf] Merge branch 'hotfix'

SHELL$ git log --oneline --graph 
*   b769fdf (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
|\  
| * 105e68f (hotfix) B
|/  
* 63dd4c0 A

SHELL$ ls
a
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for this response...I am going to try it, didn't know the crash-exit method.